# Compiler warning for unavailable methods?

Tags: objective-c, ios, compiler-construction

Is there a way to make the compiler warn for using methods that may not be available in the deployment target SDK?

For example, using `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` when the target is 4.3.

Comment: I believe `-Wall` already warns for deprecated and undeclared methods...

Comment: Actually the method exists, because base SDK is set at iOS 6.0. I guess this is beyond the work of a compiler.